# Laravel Missing argument 1 for controller method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm getting the following error after a composer update:

```
Missing argument 1 for Modules\Documentation\Http\Controllers\Frontend\DocumentationController::show()
```

The route looks like this:

```
$router->get('docs/{page}', ['as' => 'doc.show', 'uses' => 'Frontend\DocumentationController@show'])->where('page', '.*');
```

With controller method:

```
public function show($page)
{
    try {
        $title = $this->documentation->getTitle($page);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException $e) {
        App::abort('404');
    }

    $subtitle = $this->documentation->getSubTitle($page);
    $content = $this->documentation->getContent($page);

    return view('doc.index', compact('content', 'title', 'subtitle'));
}
```

This is an example of (working) same code before composer update: https://asgardcms.com/en/docs/getting-started/installation

I've tried removing the `->where()` method on the route, making parameter optional, nothing changes.

Thank you.

Comment: Does it help if you rename the `show()` method to something else?

Comment: Same issue with `showSomething()` for instance. Thanks.

Comment: what was updated in your `composer update`?

Comment: Silly me, but I guess this is just a typo. Remove every piece of code, containing 'page', type 'page' again and use copy/paste to fill the removed content. One day I made such mistake by replacing English 'p' with Russian 'р'. They look pretty much the same, right? :)

Comment: What class is your `$router` an instance of?

Comment: @dtj a lot was updated during the update, to much to list.

Comment: @adityamenon It's the laravel router. Same issue with `get()` or `Route::get()`

Comment: @NicolasWidart well, if the code was working and now it's not after the update, then it seems theres an issue with one of your dependency updates.  Did you run `composer dump-autoload`?  If it's still not working, I might recommend rolling back to an older version of your composer.lock file and incrementally updating your dependencies.